# jqgrid loading on button click in MVC3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to load jqGrid on button click in MVC 3 but i am unable to do it. Data is coming fine but nothing is happening on the page. When i click, it shows grid loading but then after nothing happens. Please see following:

**My View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";    
}
@section Javascript
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jqDataUrl = "LoadCustomerData";
        $(document).ready
        (
            function () {
                $('#btnContinue').live('click', function () {
                        bindCustomers();
                });
            }
        );

        var bindCustomers = function () {
            alert('in');
            // Set up the jquery grid
            $("#jqTable").jqGrid
                (
                    {
                        // Ajax related configurations
                        url: jqDataUrl,
                        datatype: "json",
                        mtype: "POST",

                        // Specify the column names
                        colNames: ["CustomerId", "FirstName", "LastName"],

                        // Configure the columns
                        colModel: [
                                { name: "CustomerId", index: "CustomerId", width: 40, align: "left" },
                                { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 100, align: "left" },
                                { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 200, align: "left"}],

                        // Grid total width and height
                        width: 550,
                        height: 200,

                        // Paging
                        toppager: true,
                        pager: $("#jqTablePager"),
                        rowNum: 5,
                        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                        viewrecords: true, // Specify if "total number of records" is displayed

                        // Default sorting
                        //sortname: "Id",
                        //sortorder: "asc",

                        // Grid caption
                        caption: "A Basic jqGrid - Read Only"
                    }
                ).navGrid("#jqTablePager",
                    { refresh: true, add: false, edit: false, del: false },
                        {}, // settings for edit
                        {}, // settings for add
                        {}, // settings for delete
                        {sopt: ["cn"]} // Search options. Some options can be set on column level
                );
            alert('loading finish');
        }
    </script>
}
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "Home"))
    {
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 350px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; text-align: right;">@Html.Label("lblCustomerID", "Customer ID")
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.CustomerID, new { @style = "width: 100px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; text-align: right;">@Html.Label("lblUserID", "User ID")
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.UserID, new { @style = "width: 100px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; text-align: right;">@Html.Label("lblPIC", "PIC")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.PIC, new { @style = "width: 100px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; text-align: right;">@Html.Label("lblLastName", "Last Name")
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.LastName, new { @style = "width: 100px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; text-align: right;">@Html.Label("lblInvoiceNo", "Invoice No")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormTransaction.InvoiceNumber, new { @style = "width: 100px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; text-align: right;">@Html.Label("lblEmail", "Email")
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Email, new { @style = "width: 100px" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="height: 10px;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnNewCustomer" name="btnNewCustomer" value="New Customer"
                            style="width: 100px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnEnquiry" name="btnEnquiry" value="Enquiry" style="width: 100px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnContinue" name="btnContinue" value="Continue" style="width: 100px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    }
</p>
<div>
    <table id="jqTable" class="scroll">
    </table>
    <div id="jqTablePager" />
</div>
```

**MyController**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Dynamic;
    using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;
    using NLISHelpdesk.WebUI.Models;
    using NLISHelpdesk.WebUI.Entities;
    using NLISHelpdesk.WebUI.Repositories;

    namespace NLISHelpdesk.WebUI.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Home/
            public ActionResult Home()
            {
                CustomerViewModel ViewModel = new CustomerViewModel
                {
                    Customer = new Customer(), 
                    FormTransaction = new FormTransaction(), 
                    Customers = new List<CustomerViewModel>()
                };

                return View("Home", ViewModel);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult LoadCustomerData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows,
                    bool _search, string searchField, string searchOper, string searchString)
            {
                NLISHELPDESKEntities _CustomerContext = new NLISHELPDESKEntities();
                var query = (from cus in _CustomerContext.Customers
                             select new Cust
                             {
                                CustomerID = cus.CustomerID, 
                                FirstName = cus.FirstName,
                                LastName = cus.LastName
                             }
                    ).ToList();


                Customers = query;

                // Calculate the total number of pages
                var totalRecords = query.Count();


                var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords / (double)rows);

                // Prepare the data to fit the requirement of jQGrid
                var data = (from s in Customers
                            select new
                            {
                                id = s.CustomerID,
                                cell = new object[] { s.CustomerID, s.FirstName, s.LastName}
                            }).ToArray();

                // Send the data to the jQGrid
                var jsonData = new
                {
                    total = totalPages,
                    page = page,
                    records = totalRecords,
                    rows = data.Skip((page - 1) * rows).Take(rows)
                };

                return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Class**

```
public class Cust
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

please help....

Comment: Are you using firebug or fiddler?

Comment: I'm assuming both of your alerts are firing.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes thats just for testing...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use live because the button is loaded with the page.  Also you don't need to wrap the call jquery.live... with function.  Does the alert function fire?  Are you using a JavaScript debugger?  If so, are there any errors, if not open the page in chrome and press F12 to bring up the developer tools window.

Comment: I am not using live that was just for testing. Its the actual button click event. Now my problem is I dont want to bind when the page loads. I want to bind the grid only on button click. I dont know how to achieve that...

Comment: You should post the code that is causing trouble, not other random code

Comment: You will see in the following code that I had to call bindCustomer()  which bind the jqgrid. I dont want do that rather I want to bind the grid only on button click. 

$(document).ready
        (
         function () {
            
                bindCustomers();

             $('#btnContinue').live('click', function () {
                 $('#jqTable').trigger("reloadGrid");
                 
             });

         }
        );